# How to add properties dynamically in the object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

I want to know that how many times each alphabet comes in the 'input' variable. For this I am loop through each character and storing them in an object and also how many they appeared in the sentence. But It is consoling NaN. Please show me where is the error?

```
var input = "why this kolaveri kolaveri di";
function processData(input) {
    var object = {};
    input.replace(/\s/g,"").split("").forEach(function(item){
        object[item] == 'undefined' ? object[item] = 0 && object[item]++ : object[item]++ ;
    });
    console.log(object);
}
```

Comment: For starters, `object[item] == 'undefined'` needs to be `object[item] == undefined` with no quotes around `undefined` and it would be even better to use `object[item] === undefined` with the `===` so there's no type conversion going on.  Though, I personally would use `object.hasOwnProperty(item)` myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hasOwnProperty` to check if a property exists.

```js
var input = "why this kolaveri kolaveri di";


var object = {};
input.replace(/\s/g,"").split("").forEach(function(item){
  
  // If the property doesn't exist, initialize it to 0
  if (!object.hasOwnProperty(item))
    object[item] = 0;
  
  object[item]++
});
console.log(object);
```

For the haters, you can initialize to 1 and only increment in the else. Essentially the same but a few cycles more efficient. Use whichever you think looks best.

```
  // If the property doesn't exist, initialize it to 1
  if (!object.hasOwnProperty(item))
    object[item] = 1;
  else
    object[item]++;
```

Answer (score 0):

This work

```
  typeof object[item] == 'undefined' ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You had the problem in the below line of code .

```
object[item] == 'undefined' ? object[item] = 0 && object[item]++ : object[item]++ ;
```

**Update Code:**

```js
var input = "why this kolaveri kolaveri di";
function processData(input) {
    var object = {};
    input.replace(/\s/g,"").split("").forEach(function(item){
        if(object[item] == null)
        { 
            object[item] = 0;
            object[item]++; 
        }else{
            object[item]++;
        }
    });
    console.log(object);
}

//testing here 
processData(input);
```